# USB drive will not let me copy/paste files, "permission denied"

Tags: usb, permissions, mount

So today I plugged in my 31 GB USB flash drive and opened it up. I was in the process of creating a Windows bootable device, when I tried to copy the files from my computer to the USB. I got an error message telling me I do not have permissions to add files.

- I added and removed partitions on the usb thousands of times
- I formatted it a bazillion times

And it seems I am unable to do the simple task of copying and pasting files.

I have passwords for the systems. I own the computer.

Why can't I copy files?

Formated it to ext2, fat32 and nfts: no results, same nonsense

Comment: This happens to me sometimes, not sure why.  Plug in the usb and go to /media/[yourusername] in the terminal. Type `ls -al` and see if the USB mount point is owned by root. If it is, type `sudo chown [username]:[username] [mount point]` and enter your password when asked.

Comment: What is the specific "process of creating a windows bootable device" you were using?  What commands or apps were you using?

Comment: Show us: `cat /etc/mtab` with your usb flash drive inserted

Answer (score 0):

Well for me in 2023 the solution  that I found is: Open "Disk management utility for GNOME". Select USB and apply "Repair Filesystem" (you can run after "Check File system")

Sometime the issue happend when you had previously open the USB on Windows OS

Answer (score -1):

Do as said in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1211772/can-not-change-the-usb-flash-access-permisions) last part like this:

> New update:
>
> I found solution by using gparted app by this instruction:
>
> This has been reported as a bug. But you can try this work around and
> see if it works. Install Gparted if you don't have it installed. If
> its not, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When
> it opens, run the command(s) below:
>
> sudo apt-get install gparted
>
> Once installed, open the application, and before formatting, make sure
> that you choose the right drive, and Unmount the disk by right
> clicking on the partition, and choose Unmount, then you can use the
> format To option, to format it to whatever type of file system you
> wish. Once done click on the green check mark to apply the changes.
> [image]
>
> like this:
>
> [image]
>
> unfortunately i don't saved the result log file which could help to
> understand what happened . ( but based of sudo journalctl | grep sdc
> it seems that not unmounted correctly by removing form PC USB port
> manually and ...