# can not change the USB flash access permisions

Tags: usb, permissions

i need to change the USB flash permission because i can not make new folder on it , also don't want to format it, so i have tried to use this post instruction like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/304747/my-usb-flash-does-not-have-write-permission-i-cant-copy-files-into-it-via-na):

> It is not necessary to format the flash drive or to nuke the
>   partition. You can go to mount and then change the ownership of your
>   flashdrive. On ubuntu :

```
> cd /media sudo chown -R username drivename
```

> Of course replace username by your username and drivename by the name
>   of your flash drive.
>
> Then you will be able to use nautilus as usual to copy/move/delete
>   your files.

and i have done it in my os by this way:

```
$ sudo chown 755  $USER:$USER  .
chown: cannot access 'so:so': No such file or directory
chown: changing ownership of '.': Read-only file system
```

By the way my OS username is **so** !!!
and by this code :

```
sudo chown -R  so .
chown: changing ownership of './baba/telegram/Telegram messenger  how to use2.mp4': Read-only file system
chown: changing ownership of './baba/telegram/How to Use Telegram.mp4': Read-only file system
chown: changing ownership of './baba/telegram/How to Use Telegram for Chat Support.mp4': Read-only file system
chown: changing ownership of './baba/telegram/How to Use Telegram for Chat Support [1080p].mp4': Read-only file system

...


chown: cannot access './fun/·'$'\033'':ZyÖ╕╪.≈'$'\030''7': Input/output error
chown: cannot access './fun/╓÷'$'\026''6Uuö┤.╙≤'$'\023': Input/output error
chown: changing ownership of './fun/╩Ω'$'\n''*Iiê¿.╟τ'$'\a': Read-only file system
chown: changing ownership of './fun': Read-only file system
chown: changing ownership of '.': Read-only file system
```

so why i can not have access to the Flash USB ?

Update:

based on comment of [StrabagISS_Krall](https://askubuntu.com/users/1031875/strabagiss-krall)  i have rite this code on terminal like this:

```
$ mount | grep media
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/ktube-media-downloader_6.snap on /snap/ktube-media-downloader/6 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/dev/sda6 on /media/so/EAD8A297D8A26215 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sda5 on /media/so/ACAC8B5FAC8B2346 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sdc on /media/so/09155253009 type vfat (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2)
```

and second comment :

```
 sudo journalctl | grep sdc
[sudo] password for so: 
فوریه 11 20:49:43 so-notebook kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] 15679488 512-byte logical blocks: (8.03 GB/7.48 GiB)
فوریه 11 20:49:43 so-notebook kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
فوریه 11 20:49:43 so-notebook kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
فوریه 11 20:49:43 so-notebook kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
فوریه 11 20:49:43 so-notebook kernel:  sdc:
فوریه 11 20:49:43 so-notebook kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
فوریه 11 20:49:44 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
فوریه 11 20:49:44 so-notebook udisksd[1890]: Mounted /dev/sdc at /media/so/09155253009 on behalf of uid 1000
فوریه 11 20:49:44 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 13f3d0b1)
فوریه 11 20:49:44 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): Filesystem has been set read-only
فوریه 11 20:49:44 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 13f3d0b1)
فوریه 11 20:49:54 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 13f3d0b1)
فوریه 11 20:49:56 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 13f3d0b1)
فوریه 11 20:50:05 so-notebook udisksd[1890]: Unmounted /dev/sdc on behalf of uid 1000
فوریه 11 20:50:36 so-notebook kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] 15679488 512-byte logical blocks: (8.03 GB/7.48 GiB)
فوریه 11 20:50:36 so-notebook kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
فوریه 11 20:50:36 so-notebook kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
فوریه 11 20:50:36 so-notebook kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
فوریه 11 20:50:36 so-notebook kernel:  sdc:
فوریه 11 20:50:36 so-notebook kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
فوریه 11 20:50:36 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
فوریه 11 20:50:36 so-notebook udisksd[1890]: Mounted /dev/sdc at /media/so/09155253009 on behalf of uid 1000
فوریه 11 20:50:36 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 13f3d0b1)
فوریه 11 20:50:36 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): Filesystem has been set read-only
فوریه 11 20:50:36 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 13f3d0b1)
فوریه 11 20:50:40 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 13f3d0b1)
فوریه 11 20:50:43 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 13f3d0b1)
فوریه 11 20:50:54 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 13f3d0b1)
فوریه 11 20:50:54 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 13f3d0b1)
فوریه 11 20:51:03 so-notebook udisksd[1890]: Unmounted /dev/sdc on behalf of uid 1000
فوریه 11 20:51:04 so-notebook udisksd[1890]: Ignoring SCSI command SYNCHRONIZE CACHE failure (Non-GOOD SCSI status from SGIO v3 ioctl: status=2 host_status=0 driver_status=8) on /dev/sdc
فوریه 11 20:51:04 so-notebook udisksd[1890]: Successfully sent SCSI command START STOP UNIT to /dev/sdc
فوریه 11 20:51:04 so-notebook udisksd[1890]: Powered off /dev/sdc - successfully wrote to sysfs path /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/remove
فوریه 11 20:51:13 so-notebook kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] 15679488 512-byte logical blocks: (8.03 GB/7.48 GiB)
فوریه 11 20:51:13 so-notebook kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
فوریه 11 20:51:13 so-notebook kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
فوریه 11 20:51:13 so-notebook kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
فوریه 11 20:51:13 so-notebook kernel:  sdc:
فوریه 11 20:51:13 so-notebook kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
فوریه 11 20:51:14 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
فوریه 11 20:51:14 so-notebook udisksd[1890]: Mounted /dev/sdc at /media/so/09155253009 on behalf of uid 1000
فوریه 11 20:51:14 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 13f3d0b1)
فوریه 11 20:51:14 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): Filesystem has been set read-only
فوریه 11 20:51:14 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 13f3d0b1)
فوریه 11 20:51:17 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 13f3d0b1)
فوریه 11 20:52:01 so-notebook udisksd[1890]: Unmounted /dev/sdc on behalf of uid 1000
فوریه 11 20:52:08 so-notebook kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] 15679488 512-byte logical blocks: (8.03 GB/7.48 GiB)
فوریه 11 20:52:08 so-notebook kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
فوریه 11 20:52:08 so-notebook kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
فوریه 11 20:52:08 so-notebook kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
فوریه 11 20:52:08 so-notebook kernel:  sdc:
فوریه 11 20:52:08 so-notebook kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
فوریه 11 20:52:08 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
فوریه 11 20:52:08 so-notebook udisksd[1890]: Mounted /dev/sdc at /media/so/09155253009 on behalf of uid 1000
فوریه 11 20:52:09 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 13f3d0b1)
فوریه 11 20:52:09 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): Filesystem has been set read-only
فوریه 11 20:52:09 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 13f3d0b1)
فوریه 20 13:29:24 so-notebook kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] 15679488 512-byte logical blocks: (8.03 GB/7.48 GiB)
فوریه 20 13:29:24 so-notebook kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
فوریه 20 13:29:24 so-notebook kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
فوریه 20 13:29:24 so-notebook kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
فوریه 20 13:29:24 so-notebook kernel:  sdc:
فوریه 20 13:29:24 so-notebook kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
فوریه 20 13:29:25 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
فوریه 20 13:29:25 so-notebook udisksd[1971]: Mounted /dev/sdc at /media/so/09155253009 on behalf of uid 1000
فوریه 20 13:29:25 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 13f3d0b1)
فوریه 20 13:29:25 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): Filesystem has been set read-only
فوریه 20 13:29:25 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 13f3d0b1)
فوریه 20 13:30:11 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 13f3d0b1)
فوریه 20 13:30:11 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start eecfac8d)
فوریه 20 13:30:11 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start b2937051)
فوریه 20 13:30:11 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 8e6f4c2d)
فوریه 20 13:30:11 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 523310f0)
فوریه 20 13:30:11 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 2e0febcc)
فوریه 20 13:30:11 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start f1d2af90)
فوریه 20 13:30:11 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start cdae8b6c)
فوریه 20 13:30:11 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 91724f30)
فوریه 20 13:30:11 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 6d4e2b0c)
فوریه 20 13:30:29 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 13f3d0b1)
فوریه 20 13:30:29 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start eecfac8d)
فوریه 20 13:30:29 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 13f3d0b1)
فوریه 20 13:30:29 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start eecfac8d)
فوریه 20 13:30:38 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 13f3d0b1)
فوریه 20 13:30:43 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 13f3d0b1)
فوریه 20 13:32:06 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 13f3d0b1)
فوریه 20 13:32:06 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start eecfac8d)
فوریه 20 13:32:06 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start b2937051)
فوریه 20 13:32:06 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 8e6f4c2d)
فوریه 20 13:32:06 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 523310f0)
فوریه 20 13:32:06 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 2e0febcc)
فوریه 20 13:32:06 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start f1d2af90)
فوریه 20 13:32:06 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start cdae8b6c)
فوریه 20 13:32:06 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 91724f30)
فوریه 20 13:32:06 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 6d4e2b0c)
فوریه 20 13:34:21 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 13f3d0b1)
فوریه 20 13:34:21 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start eecfac8d)
فوریه 20 13:34:21 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start b2937051)
فوریه 20 13:34:21 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 8e6f4c2d)
فوریه 20 13:34:21 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 523310f0)
فوریه 20 13:34:21 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 2e0febcc)
فوریه 20 13:34:21 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start f1d2af90)
فوریه 20 13:34:21 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start cdae8b6c)
فوریه 20 13:34:21 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 91724f30)
فوریه 20 13:34:21 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 6d4e2b0c)
فوریه 20 13:38:56 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 13f3d0b1)
فوریه 20 13:38:56 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start eecfac8d)
فوریه 20 13:38:56 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start b2937051)
فوریه 20 13:38:56 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 8e6f4c2d)
فوریه 20 13:38:56 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 523310f0)
فوریه 20 13:38:56 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 2e0febcc)
فوریه 20 13:38:56 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start f1d2af90)
فوریه 20 13:38:56 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start cdae8b6c)
فوریه 20 13:38:56 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 91724f30)
فوریه 20 13:38:56 so-notebook kernel: FAT-fs (sdc): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 6d4e2b0c)
```

I also get this error (**(udisks-error-quark, 0)**) for repairing the USB flash by disk manger app of Ubuntu :

[image]

***New update:***

I found solution by using gparted app by [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377253/unable-to-format-usb-drive-with-disks-udisks-error-quark-0) instruction:

> This has been reported as a bug. But you can try this work around and
>   see if it works. Install Gparted if you don't have it installed. If
>   its not, just press Ctrl+Alt+T on your keyboard to open Terminal. When
>   it opens, run the command(s) below:
>
> sudo apt-get install gparted
>
> Once installed, open the application, and before formatting, make sure
>   that you choose the right drive, and Unmount the disk by right
>   clicking on the partition, and choose Unmount, then you can use the
>   format To option, to format it to whatever type of file system you
>   wish. Once done click on the green check mark to apply the changes.
>
> [image]

like this:

[image]

unfortunately i don't saved the result log file which could help to understand what happened . ( but based of `sudo journalctl | grep sdc` it seems that not unmounted correctly by removing form PC USB port manually and ...

Thanks.

Comment: Your drive is mounted read-only. Could you please post the output of `mount | grep media`?

Comment: updated as you want.

Comment: Thank you. Could also please add the output of `sudo journalctl | grep sdc` aswell?