# Internal NTFS drives not mounting RW

Tags: 20.04, ntfs, read-only

I am trying to move over from Win10 to Ubuntu (20.04 in this instance) so am beginning to work more in depth with Linux (have played a little with RPi's). I have internal SATA 2x1TB SSD's that are NTFS however when I try to access them I can only read them.

Searching online it says about install ntfs-3g to gain writeable access but that hasn't worked for me.

These are the settings I have been using:
[Mount Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTdn9.png)

I checked the permissions for the mount point and it says:

```
drwxrwxrwx  1 root root 49152 Jul 31 15:11 8442159642158DD4
```

Is it that the directory is owned by root causing the issues?

Not sure where to go from here, everything I have found online says more about having issues getting the drives to mount, I can do that I just can't write to them :D

Comment: This is not a driver problem. You don't shutdown Windows properly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Comment: The following answers should be relevant for you: [Copying files from Windows to dedicated directories in your Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1357243/how-do-i-copy-my-windows-7-derived-files-off-my-usb-to-ubuntu/1357548#1357548) and [Mount NTFS partition in a USB drive with custom permissions and owner](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/956072#956072). Please notice that **you can use the same mount option as in these answers in your `/etc/fstab` file**.

Comment: I agree with the two first comments. Please shut Windows down properly: Hibernation and "fast startup" leave the file system in a dirty state, and Linux tools mount dirty systems read-only to avoid creating problems. But you may also want/need to mount the NTFS file sysstem with the mount options that I suggest in the links.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I'll have a look this evening. In my defence, I did shut down Windows correctly, as much as Windows allows you to. Although I am aware that Windows does do the fast boot hibernation, I didn't realise that this would cause issues for Linux, let alone cause issues on drives that are not the boot drives

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments provided giving me some insight into how Windows says one thing and does another, my solution was to "make" Windows actually shutdown cleanly by telling it to reboot then shutting off the machine as it started up again.

I remember hearing somewhere that when you reboot Windows it actually clears everything and boots in a clean state (i.e. not waking up from hibernation).

After I was able to switch out the Windows drive for the Ubuntu one and now I can access the 2 NTFS drives with full RW privileges!

Thanks for the assistance :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :-)